# Como eu valido um campo de e-mail em Dart?

Tags: regex, dart, validação

Criei um simples projeto em [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org) cuja intensão é validar um campo de e-mail quando um botão é clicado, mostrando uma mensagem de erro.

Contudo, a função [RegExp.hasMath](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/RegExp.html#hasMatch) esta retornando sempre falso. Não sei o que pode estar errado.

Abaixo segue o código HTML e em seguida o Dart.

```html
<!-- formulario.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste e-mail</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form">
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error">
        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
    </div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="validate.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```dart
// validate.dart
import 'dart:html';

void main(){
  querySelector('#submit').onClick.listen(verifyEmail);
}

void verifyEmail(Event e) {
  String email = querySelector('#inputEmail').text;
  querySelector('#errorMessage').text = 
      isValidEmail(email) ? '' : 'E-mail inválido!';
}

bool isValidEmail(String email){
  RegExp reg = new RegExp(r"^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$");
  return reg.hasMatch(email);
}
```

Comment: Experimente ler `querySelector('#inputEmail').value` em vez de `text`.

Comment: Não há a propriedade `value` na classe `Element` retornada pelo método `querySelector`.

Comment: Oops. Talvez `(querySelector('#inputEmail') as InputElement).value`?

Comment: Incluí sua solução @Guilherme. Grato!

Comment: No caso deveria haver uma resposta ao invés de editar a questão. Vou escrever uma com mais detalhes.

Comment: Concordo, no entanto, neste caso, o erro encontrado não tem nada a ver com a pergunta, por isso editei para incluir a solução. Mas se isso não tem nada a ver, poste a resposta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema aqui foi o uso da propriedade [`text`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/Element.html#text) na expectativa de que este retornasse o texto digitado pelo usuário. O que essa propriedade faz no entanto é ler o conteúdo dentro do nodo, similar ao [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent). Observer que o `text` de um `input` é sempre em branco já que a tag não pode conter filhos.

```html
<p>Texto <strong>aqui</strong></p>   <!-- text = "Texto aqui" -->
```

O correto é ler a propriedade [`value`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html#value). Mas para tal você deve ter um `InputElement` em vez de um `Element`, um *cast* precisa ser efetuado antes de ler a propriedade duas formas de fazer isso:

```dart
// Explícito:
String email = (querySelector('#inputEmail') as InputElement).value;

// Implícito:
InputElement inputEmail = querySelector('#inputEmail');
String email = inputEmail.value;
```

Você pode também não fazer *cast* algum e ignorar o aviso gerado (evite ignorar avisos):

```dart
String email = querySelector('#inputEmail').value;
```

Sobre o seu `isValidEmail` retornar sempre falso, ele está correto. Você estava na verdade passando `""` para ele.